# Cannot Loop Through Rows of a Table in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are lots of examples on the internet, including SO, telling people how to loop through the rows of a table and get the values using Javascript or Jquery. Unfortunately, none of these examples work for me:

JavaScript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tbInvoiceDetails");

var rowLength = table.rows.length;

for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i += 1) {
    var row = table.rows[i];

    var cell = row.cells[10].innerHTML;
}
```

This gets:

```
<input id="InvoiceDetails_0__Title" name="InvoiceDetails[0].Vat" value="0" type="hidden">0
```

How can I get the value (=0) from this?

JQuery:

```
$("#tbInvoiceDetails tr").each(function () {
//Code
}
```

This simply does not work. I have tried every combination I can think of inside the "" and nothing works.

Table HTML with One Line:

```
<tbody id="tbInvoiceDetails">
  <tr id="trInvoiceDetail0">
    <td style="display:none">
      <input name="InvoiceDetails.Index" value="0" type="hidden"></td>
    <td style="display:none"><input name="InvoiceDetails[0].id" value="-1" type="hidden"></td>
    <td style="display:none"><input name="InvoiceDetails[0].InvoiceId" value="0" type="hidden"></td>
    <td><input id="InvoiceDetails_0__Title" name="InvoiceDetails[0].LineTypeId" value="1" type="hidden">1</td>
    <td><input id="InvoiceDetails_0__Title" name="InvoiceDetails[0].AllocationCodeId" value="19" type="hidden">2030 6016750 KQ73020394 11014008</td>
    <td><input id="InvoiceDetails_0__Title" name="InvoiceDetails[0].GspId" value="" type="hidden"></td>
    <td><input id="InvoiceDetails_0__Title" name="InvoiceDetails[0].RunTypeId" value="" type="hidden"></td>
    <td><input id="InvoiceDetails_0__Title" name="InvoiceDetails[0].BillingPeriodFromDate" value="06/08/2015" type="hidden">06/08/2015</td>
    <td><input id="InvoiceDetails_0__Title" name="InvoiceDetails[0].BillingPeriodToDate" value="19/08/2015" type="hidden">19/08/2015</td>
    <td><input id="InvoiceDetails_0__Title" name="InvoiceDetails[0].Net" value="9999" type="hidden">9999</td>
    <td><input id="InvoiceDetails_0__Title" name="InvoiceDetails[0].Vat" value="0" type="hidden">0</td>
    <td><input id="InvoiceDetails_0__Title" name="InvoiceDetails[0].InterestPay" value="0" type="hidden">0</td>
    <td><input id="InvoiceDetails_0__Title" name="InvoiceDetails[0].InterestReceiveable" value="0" type="hidden">0</td>
    <td><input id="InvoiceDetails_0__Title" name="InvoiceDetails[0].VatCodeId" value="8" type="hidden">8</td>
    <td><input class="btn" id="btnRemoveInvoiceDetail" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow(0);" type="button"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: 1. Include your HTML. 2. What do you mean by "value" in *"This gets the innerHTML including other tags but not the value"*? Regarding your jQuery snippet at the end, it absolutely **does** work for looping through the `tr` elements in an element with the `id` `tbInvoiceDetails`.

Comment: please add HTML, also do you want to get values in each tr or td?

Comment: Perhaps — and this may sound crazy — include **the part of the HTML you want to loop over**. That's a lovely header row, but I don't imagine you *actually* want to loop through an empty `tbody`. And, as @T.J.Crowder asked, please explain what you mean by "value". Table cells, and certainly table rows, don't actually have values. Do you mean their inner text? The value of some input field(s) inside? More things that might be more clear if you actually showed the data rows.

Comment: I understand that the table is initially empty. However, once you're looping over it, it won't be. There will be rows. Show us those rows. You can most likely Inspect the table (or a single row) in your [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), then do something like Right-Click the element and select Copy from the context menu to get the HTML of the row(s) in question. Include that above.

Comment: Note also that `id` values **must** be unique in the document. You have 11 different `input` elements that all have the `id` `InvoiceDetails_0__Title`. That's neither valid nor useful.

Comment: But with the HTML, it's now possible to answer the question (or will be if/when it's reopened): `$("#tbInvoiceDetails tr").each(function () { var $row = $(this); var vat = $row.find('input[name="InvoiceDetails[0].Vat"]').val(); /* ...other fields here... */ });` Note that field values are strings.

Comment: Or — assuming that the names will actually change per-row (`InvoiceDetails[1].Vat`, etc.) — you can get them via the index in a single query: `$('#tbInvoiceDetails tr td:nth-child(11) input').each( function() { var vat = +this.value; } );`  The `+` will force a numeric conversion of the string value.

Answer (score 0):

Going the by-column-position route:

jQuery:

```
$('#tbInvoiceDetails tr td:nth-child(11) input').each(
  function() {
    var val = this.value;

    console.log(val);
  }
);
```

Pure JS:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tbInvoiceDetails");

var rowLength = table.rows.length;

for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i += 1) {    
  var input = table.rows[i].cells[10].firstElementChild;

  var val = input.value;
  console.log(val);
}
```